# How to use Cloudflare SSL with Hostinger

Tags: ssl, https, dns, web, ssl-certificate

recently i got a domain for my brothers so they could use it on their minecraft server, but didnt know how to code or didnt have any money to use it, so I helped them.

I decided that i wanted to use cloudflare as my SSL provider, since they give a free shared cloudflare certificate, but im having issues with it, here is my problem:

1. When i go to https://, it displays:

https://axiatinc.stop-pings.me/377ff2a3.png

I have absolutely no idea why it does this, it is secure, but none of my site data shows, I have tried to go to like https://example.com/index.php or https://example.com/folder/image.jpg, but nothing works. Id really appreciate some help with this, as I want to get HTTPS up and running hopefully tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I have it temporarily fixed by using flexible SSL instead of Full, i still want to use full, if someone could help me be able to use full and not get the error message that would be great!

Comment: Do you use Hostinger's Cloudflare service or Cloudflare complete service at cloudflare.com?